# Inject request scoped object at run time asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, structuremap

I have a middleware in the ASP.NET Core pipeline where im injecting an object at runtime like this

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
 _container.Inject(someObject);
 await _requestDelegate(context);
}
```

The problem that im facing now is that for every request its injecting an instance of this and is bloating my container.
If I do `_container.GetAllInstances<SomeType>()`, im getting 100+ objects. Is there any way by which we can inject the object scoped to the request and dispose off the object when the request has finished ?

Comment: Seems you are mixing runtime data with object composition, which is [not a great idea](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/).

Comment: As far as I know you can use the scoped lifetime with AddScope method for your objects/per request. The container IoC will handle for you when to Dispose the object. If you want to retrieve objects with that were registered with the same interface type then you can inject them by name. Which is the reason to. Inject an object per request? Were is going to be used later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependency Injection shouldn't be configured at runtime for each requests, but rather at application start for the whole application.

For per-request instances managing request-data using `HttpContext.Items` is a better approach. It's a Key-Value store intended for shared objects across a single HTTP request.

In your middleware you can add the object to the `HttpContext.Items` collection:
`context.Items.Add("someObjectKey", someObject);`

Then in a Controller (or anywhere you have the HttpContext), you can get the object:

```
if (context.Items.TryGetValue("someObjectKey", out object objSomeObject) 
    && objSomeObject is SomeObjectType someObject)) {
    // Do anything with your object here
}
```

---

If you really want to use DI, you could create a helper class with scoped lifetime which gets the current `HttpContext` with `IHttpContextAccessor` and offers your object in a type-safe way.

```
public class SomeObjectAccessor
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public SomeObjectAccessor(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public SomeObject Object {
        get
        {
            if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Items != null && _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("someObjectKey", out object objSomeObject))
                return objSomeObject as SomeObject;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively that class could also act as a factory and creates the objects based on the HttpContext on first access, then you wouldn't use `HttpContext.Items`.  But that depends on the use-case here.

Comment: Thanks for the above, will give it a shot, but I found another way too. The context object contains a property called RequestServices, which gives me the service provider. Using the service provider I can modify the object too, something like this var someObj = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<SomeWrapper>()  I want to know whether this is a good approach too

Comment: Also I think we should avoid the direct use of HttpContext as mocking becomes difficult, we should use some sort of wrapper like the one you have mentioned.

Comment: Remember to add services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); to get a IHttpContextAccessor  instance

Comment: Good luck with that

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are trying to do. What's the purpose of injecting an object at runtime for every request?

You set up your DI in `ConfigureServices` method using ServicesCollection and use the built-in `AddScoped` method to inject the object that will be valid for the particular request.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped(typeof(someclass), someObject);
}
```

if you need to access the instance of someObject in your middleware. Simply add the dependency as an additional parameter to the Invoke method

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IYourDependency someObject)
{
    await _requestDelegate(context);
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I read some values from the request header which I want to inject at runtime, the application wont be aware about the instance. It will be created and injected based on the header data

Comment: Which IoC container are you using? It's not recommended to inject a container into controllers/classes, but if you must, literally all containers support the scoped injection. The terminology they use might be different e.g. InstancePerRequest (Autofac) or AddScoped (Asp.Net Core). So based on your logic that if the request header is present, inject the instance to the container. I am still little baffled as what would you do with that instance after it is injected into the container?